# Translating ecore models (accompanying OCL expressions) to alloy specification

Tags: transformation, alloy, ocl, ecore

I am looking to see if there is any tool or engine which translates Ecore (meta-)models to Alloy specification?

if it does this translation considering accompanying OCL expressions, it would be great :)

Thx

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of research papers on the topic of translating between Alloy and UML.  A quick google scholar search for "ocl alloy" returned more than 6000 results.  Here are some that seemed the most relevant:

- [On challenges of model transformation from UML to Alloy](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10270-008-0110-3)
- [UML2ALLOY: A TOOL FOR LIGHTWEIGHT MODELLING OF DISCRETE EVENT SYSTEMS](http://pdf.aminer.org/000/258/714/uml_alloy_a_tool_for_lightweight_modelling_of_discrete_event.pdf)
- [Analysis of model transformations via alloy](http://is.uni-paderborn.de/uploads/tx_sibibtex/modevva07.pdf#page=53)
- [Formal refactoring for UML class diagrams](http://twiki.cin.ufpe.br/twiki/pub/SPG/GroupPublications/sbes2005.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

A research paper that explicitly focus on translating UML class diagrams annotated with OCL is "[Translating between Alloy specifications and UML class diagrams annotated with OCL](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10270-013-0353-5)", by Alcino Cunha, Ana Garis and Daniel Riesco.

You can check out the implementation [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/alloymda/). It should be trivially adaptable to Ecore meta-models.

Answer (score 0):

An Eclipse plugin called Lightning allows to do such transformations. It is currently in test phase, and will normally be available online at the end of the week. (I will edit this answer with the update-site link when it will be release)

If you can't wait that long, I might arrange you an early access.

edit :
update site > http://lightning.gforge.uni.lu/update-site